# Postgres COPY TO NULL integers

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I have a CSV that contains various columns.  One of the columns contains integer data.  However, when running a copy to:

```
COPY soc 
FROM '~/soc.asc'
WITH DELIMITER '$';
```

I'm getting the following:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY soc, line 1, column soc_code: ""
```

as it appears that Postgres is trying to stick an empty string in an integer.  How can I fix this?  I don't really want to fudge my schema to suit the import if it can be helped.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can tell postgres to interpret [some value as NULL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html), for example:

```
COPY soc FROM '~/soc.asc' WITH DELIMITER AS '$' NULL AS ''
```