# psql copy command will not interpret NULL values properly

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to copy values from a csv (with headers) into a table. I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821068/postgres-copy-to-null-integers) which says to specify the NULL value, but it does not seem to have an effect for me. This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE stops
(
  stop_id           text PRIMARY KEY,
  --stop_code         text NULL,
  stop_name         text NOT NULL,
  --stop_desc         text NULL,
  stop_lat          double precision NOT NULL,
  stop_lon          double precision NOT NULL,
  zone_id           integer NULL,
  stop_url          text NULL,
  location_type     boolean NULL,
  parent_station    text NULL
);

\copy stops from './stops.txt' with csv header NULL AS ''
```

I also tried using the `\N` character like so:

```
\copy stops from './stops.txt' with csv header NULL AS '\N'
```

But it does not seem to have an effect.

I have also tried experimenting with a solution found [here](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-copy-force-null/) which looks like this:

```
\copy agency from './agency.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv header, FORCE_NULL(zone_id))
```

But this seems to throw a syntax error at the `csv_header` part.

Version is 9.6.

This is an excerpt of the csv:

```
stop_id,stop_name,stop_lat,stop_lon,zone_id,stop_url,location_type,parent_station
"de:07334:1714:1:1","Wörth Alte Bahnmeisterei","49.048742345982","8.26622538039577","","","","Parent1714"
"de:07334:1714:1:2","Wörth Alte Bahnmeisterei","49.0484420719247","8.26673742010779","","","","Parent1714"
"de:07334:1721:1:1","Maximiliansau Eisenbahnstraße","49.0373071007148","8.29789997731824","","","","Parent1721"
"de:07334:1721:2:2","Maximiliansau Eisenbahnstraße","49.0371363175998","8.29896897250649","","","","Parent1721"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this seems to throw a syntax error at the csv_header part.

Put a comma after csv:

```
\copy agency from './agency.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, FORCE_NULL(zone_id,location_type))
```

Apparently `FORCE_NULL` is required for non-text columns, when using the empty string to specify NULL.

Comment: That was it, thanks. A little more tuning was necessary so for anyone who comes across this in the future, the full working command is `\copy stops from './stops.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, FORCE_NULL(zone_id, location_type))`